# Difference between "Ashamed" and "Embarrassed"

Tags: meaning, word-difference

What difference is there between "Ashamed" and "Embarrassed"?

Is it that "Ashamed" is more serious than "Embarrassed"? For example, you'd say "I was embarrassed to be wearing mis-matching socks", while you'd say "I was ashamed of that stupid argument I had"?

I came across https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88320/embarassed-vs-ashamed, but it had only one answer, and it didn't feel definitive enough.

Comment: I found this, does it answer your question: http://englishhelponline.me/2010/02/14/the-difference-between-words-embarrassed-and-ashamed/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comparing these two definitions from OxfordDictionaries shows the two words obviously overlap...

> [**embarrass**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/embarrass) *- cause (someone) to feel awkward, self-conscious, or **ashamed***
>   [**ashamed**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ashamed) *- **embarrassed** or guilty because of one’s actions, characteristics, or associations*

But two key differences are...

> 1: ***embarrassed*** more often applies to *socially awkward* contexts, rather than *regret, guilt*
>    2: You don't usually feel ***embarrassed*** when you're alone

I don't really like OP's idea that being *ashamed* is more "serious" than being *embarrassed*. I might feel *ashamed* if I discovered I was the only person in my road who didn't leave a Christmas tip for the postie, but that would be nothing compared to how *embarrassed* I'd feel if I discovered said postie knew exactly what was in all the packages she'd delivered over the preceding year!

---

TL;DR: ***Shame*** is mainly a response to having transgressed your own (internal) moral code. ***Embarrassment*** is more about feeling that others may laugh or look down on you for something you did.

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand, **embarrassed** is used only when there are "other" people (particularly, around you) who can see the bad thing you just did.  Embarrassment is a reaction caused by fear of being **judged** by other people as a wrong(or stupid) person.

But, **ashamed** is used for repenting about something you did, even when there is no one to see your fault.  Shame is a reaction caused by **self-introspection** of what a person did.

You can be either ashamed or embarrassed or both about spilling your drink in public.

In case you have a secretly leaked question paper of tomorrow's exam in your bag, you can only be ashamed.  Of course, your embarrassment will begin after someone discovers the leaked question paper in your bag.